# Debugging jetty on a failed start

Tags: solr, jetty, cloud

I've deployed Solr in Jetty 9.0.6 on a Debian machine and sometimes when i try to start it up, it fails without giving me any clues why. The <>.stderrout.log file is allways empty.
How could I enable logging or verbose output for the start operation?
I'm doing:

```
$ sudo service jetty start
Starting Jetty . . . . . . . FAILED Tue Oct 15 11:10:18 CEST 2013
```

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Jetty 9.0.6 you pass into the part of your service that calls `${jetty.home}/start.jar` the extra [`--daemon` command line variable](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.6.v20130930/jetty-start/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/start/Main.java#L218-L247) and look for the `start.log` files. (These files are usually found at the [`${jetty.logs}/start.log`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.6.v20130930/jetty-start/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/start/Main.java#L218-L247) location.

Along with that, also include the [`-DDEBUG=true`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.0.6.v20130930/jetty-start/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/start/Config.java#L948-L956) to enable debug of the startup process, as well as enabling the debug on Jetty itself (until the actual logger kicks in).

Finally, if you want the default Jetty StdErrLog to log at debug level too, add the `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG` to the command line as well.

To put this in non-service terms ...

```
[jetty-distribution-9.0.6.v20130930]$ java -jar start.jar --daemon -DDEBUG=true -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG
```

As for how to do that with a debian service, I have no clue.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do it by modifying the java options in /etc/init.d/jetty - adding the oones provided by you.